# keeping a public static arraylist in a activity in android, is a good practice?

Tags: android, arraylist, static

I am developing a android application. In it's splash activity I download a JSON String(brings student details) and makes a Student ArrayList(this arraylist is public and static) that contains Student Id,Name,Age,description. Then the application shows a list view of all the student names.Then I wrote on list item clicked shows the detail view of that student. I wanna know if this a good practice to use a public static arraylist in a application that uses it over all the activities ??
If not what should I use.??
Should I save them in a SQLite database ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice for sure!
You have two options in this case.

1. If you would be downloading those strings every time you run a fresh app then it would be better to keep that list in a `Singleton` class.
2. Or if you just want to download the first time and then probably not much again in future then definitely save it in the database.

Comment: Can you explain me please why it would be better to create the variable in a singleton class rather than make it a static variable.

Comment: Having a static arrayList inside an activity which is going to be destroyed and might be recreated later point of time is definitely not a good practice. I answered based on what he asked for. Rather than keeping it in activity, it's definitely better to keep that array inside a plain java singleton class.

Comment: Ok.I agree with you.If I create a static class and put that variable in that class,then it also be fine,I think so.And beyond that SharedPreference is also a good option.Hope you agree

Comment: I added this to database. But can you give me a example that how to create a singleton class using that string or please point me a example about how to keep my static array in singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

Save data in SQLite database is the best practice. Also try to create **ContentProvider** for your data.